# Return statement of child process when forking()

Tags: unix, process, operating-system, fork, child-process

How many lines of Hello are printed?

```
int main(){
    fn();
     printf("Hello \n");
    exit(0);
    }

  void fn(){     
    if(fork() == 0){
     fork();
      printf("Hello \n");
    }
    return;
  }
```

I am new to this topic and wanted to learn on how the child processes behave.
I see that the answer to the above question is 5.

I do know that 3 statements would be printed.

**My question :**

Does the return statement, return the child processes to the main() function 
    and hence the child processes execute from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the return statement, return the child processes to the main() function and hence the child processes execute from there?

Yes they keep executing like how your main process executes, unless you `exit()` prematurely in the children.